# is it possible to get a IMAGE from chrome theme.?

Tags: browsers, google-chrome

I downloaded a theme form extension of the **chrome browser**.

My Question is

> is it possible to find the background image in `Local Disks`??

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *inspect* the *HTML web page* like any other *HTML web page* and save any resources that have been downloaded to your computer...

```
Inspect (Ctrl+Shift+I) > Resources > Frames > (newtab) > Images
```